# How use third-party plugins after install in npm?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I install plugin (for instance normalize.css or jQuery) with npm install command.

```
npm install normalize.css --save
npm install jquery --save
```

I see them in package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "normalize.css": "^7.0.0"
  }
```

What next? How i can use it in my project? I'm using gulp and I do not know what to do next.

Comment: You may need to use another tool like [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

Comment: Did you get any error?

Comment: all the installed `css` or `js` files will be inside a folder `node_modules`. You can manually add `<link href="/node_modules/../abc.css" />` and `<script src="/node_modules/../abc.js" />` in your main html file. Or add `node_module` while bundling your js and css using gulp.js

Comment: Are you starting a new project? Or do you want to integrate it in your existing project?

Comment: New project. In folder there are a lot of unnecessary js and css.  Manually add <link> or <script>... And if there are many plug-ins? Can there is a way of automation?

Answer (score -1):

There are two main ways to make use of it.

**Approach 1:** use normalize.css as a starting point for your own project’s base CSS, customising the values to match the design’s requirements.

**Approach 2:** include normalize.css untouched and build upon it, overriding the defaults later in your CSS if necessary.